# How to filter useState hook Array and push & pull data to that array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I am searching for filter React useState hook array. Not getting any answer. Please help me.

I define useState string array-

```
const [filterBrand, setFilterBrand] = useState<string[]>([]);
```

Here is my function for filtering this array and push, pull data-

```
const brandHandler = (item: string) => {
    //Here I need if filterBrand already have the 
      item then remove it and update the state, 
      else add the item to this array and update 
      the state
}
```

Here I need to check if `item` already have in `filterBrand`. then remove it from `filterBrand` and update the `State`.
Else I need to add the `item` to `filterBrand` and update the `State`

I already tried it-

```
const brandHandler = (item: string) => {
    const items: string[] = [...filterBrand];
    if (!filterBrand.includes(item)) {
        items.push(item)
    } else {
        return items.filter(f => f !== item)
    }
    setFilterBrand(prevState => ({ ...prevState, ...items }));
}
```

But getting this error-

`Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance.\nIn order to be iterable, non-array objects must have a [Symbol.iterator]() method`

Answer (score 1):

Do this

```
// setFilterBrand(prevState => [ ...prevState, ...items ]); would work
setFilterBrand(items) // likely what you want instead
```

instead of

```
setFilterBrand(prevState => ({ ...prevState, ...items }));
```

You are transforming your array into an object for some reason here

Full code:

```
const brandHandler = (item: string) => {
    let items: string[] = [...filterBrand];
    if (!filterBrand.includes(item)) {
        items.push(item)
    } else {
        items = items.filter(f => f !== item)
    }
    setFilterBrand(items);
}
```

Comment: Others is okay?

Comment: Based on the logic of the question I think you just want `setFilterBrand(items);`.

Comment: But why not removing the item, when matched.

Comment: I updated my answer to show full code.